# What method is the best to copy files from one server to another using PHP

Tags: php

I need to copy a couple of files over from one server to another using PHP. Now I currently use PHP FTP functionality which is ok but causes issues. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: I am also using PHP FTP functionality to upload code form one server to another server, but i am getting error, it comes out in the else condition. Can you pls share your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FTP is a good way to do this. It handles the authentication, and there are [native PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) to use with FTP.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), or [`sftp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)

However, if restricted to PHP only, try [`ssh2_sftp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

required - [pecl ssh2 package](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php)

with the proper configured ssh public key, you don't even require to supply password

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is usually **rsync**, especially if you need to copy a directory structure. It's not strictly a PHP method, but you can call using `shell_exec()` or backtick syntax:

```
`rsync -acz /files/to/copy/ user@remotehost:/target/dir/`
```

You'll need to use public key authentication, but there are plenty of tutorials around on that. If you know the location of a public key file that will get you into the remote server, you can use the `-e` switch:

```
`rsync -acze 'ssh -i /path/to/your.key' /files...`
```

Check out [the rsync website](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) for more info.

PHP's backtick syntax works with *variable interpolation*, so you can use variables like `$source`, `$target` etc in your syntax.